# Parse command line with uncertain number of arguments

Tags: c, coredump, argv

I have a concern on how to parse the arguments when number of arguments is not certain.

For example we can consider any core dump application.

On registering an application(ex: `store_dump`) in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` the `store_dump` application is called whenever a native crash occurs. We can give various options during registration as to what arguments we would like to receive.

My options are - `%p %e %s` that is `(pid, executable file name(thread name), signal number)`

So I plan to read the arguments as

```
argv[1] -> pid
argv[2] -> thread name
argv[3] -> signal number
```

This owrks fine unless I have space in the thread name. In case if `thread name` contains space, it is split into two arguments as under.

```
argv[1] -> pid
argv[2] -> thread name (first part)
argv[3] -> thread name (second part)
argv[4] -> signal number
```

So how should I write a proper logic to parse these arguments? I cannot always hardcode argv[3] to signal number. Is there a generic way?

One option I see is to keep the thread name at last. But I feel there should be some better solution than this.

Could someone suggest.

Comment: can you not check `argc` and branch based on how many arguments you have?

Comment: Can't you just put quotation marks around the arguments?

Comment: @KerrekSB In the case I mentioned, kernel will give the arguments, so it is not possible to put quotes around it.

Comment: @RedAlert That will not solve the issue in my case. Request you to go-through my use case once again

Comment: @mk.. your use case asks how to parse command line arguments, typically that is done with `argc`

Comment: I meant  to put the quotation marks into the pattern string..?

Comment: Can you not get `thread name` from the `pid` and vice versa? You can then treat the last argument as the `signal number`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry if my understanding is wrong. The pattern is formulated by Linux kernel on a crash. So i should modify it to append some quotes. This is not a feasible thing to do as a generic solution.

Comment: @vikramls It is possible. But this is executed when a process is crashed. So i dont really want to rely on the /proc information at this stage.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of putting `"%e"` into the core_pattern, but that doesn't work, since the pattern isn't parsed by a shell; it's simply substituted and tokenized immediately. I guess what you could do is add magic separators: `|/bin/myhandler MAGIC1 %p MAGIC2 %e MAGIC3`, and then separate on those separators. You'll still lose whitespace in the thread name, but at least you know roughly what the thread name looks like.

Comment: @KerrekSB Perfect. Could you please submit it as answer?

Comment: @mk..: Actually, if the thread name is the only thing that can have whitespace, just move it to the end of the argument list and consider all the remaining arguments to make up the thread name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Change your core pattern to `%p %s %e`. Since `%e` is the only thing that can get replaced with whitespace, you can simply consider *all* the trailing arguments (i.e. `argv[i]` for `i > 2`) to make up the thread name.

Option 2: If you have multiple specifiers that may be replaced with whitespace (e.g. repeated instances of `%e`, or `%h`), you can set add magic separators to your arguments which you hope will never appear as part of a thread name, and then look for those as you iterate over the arguments:

```
|store_dump MAGIC1 %p MAGIC2 %e MAGIC3
```

Neither option is perfect in the sense that any whitespace in the thread name is normalized, so you cannot reconstruct the actual name accurately. For example, you cannot distinguish threads that only differ in the length of their embedded whitespace runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that the `signal number` will always be last, just access the `argv[argc-1]`.

For example:

```
int pid, signal_number;

pid = atoi(argv[1]);
signal_number = atoi(argv[argc-1]);

// process name can be constructed from concatenating argv[2] to argv[argc-2]
```

Comment: Like this approach - just concatenate the middle arguments to form `thread name`.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from doing something like this?

```
int pid, signal_number;
char* thread_name;

pid = atoi(argv[1]);
if(argc == 4)
{
    thread_name = argv[2];
    signal_number = atoi(argv[3]);
}
else if(argc == 5)
{
    thread_name = malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + strlen(argv[3]) + 1); //leaks
    strcpy(thread_name, argv[2]);
    strcat(thread_name, argv[3]);
    signal_number = atoi(argv[4]);
}
```

Incomplete as you still need to free `thread_name` in the event you get 5 arguments, but that's not very complicated.

Comment: I dont like it. Personal choice. What if thread name contains two spaces? this is not fool proof. Also, tomorrow there can be new parameter that can have white space.. This approach could have been most obvious but it is bad design according to me.

Comment: None of the approaches presented here will guard you from the thread name containing two spaces, you will always lose the information about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is one way to read process command line arguments
// when the number of arguments (argc) can be 4 or 5

// argv[0] is always current pgm name and counts as any argument

if( 4 == argc ) { // process 3 arguments } 
else if( 5 == argc ) { // process 4 arguments }
else // unexpected argument list, handle error
endif

or

switch( argc )
{
    case 4:
    // call function to handle 3 arguments
    break;
    case 5: 
    // call function to handle 4 arguments
    break;
    default:
    // handle error condition
    break;
}
```